# include template from another extension ezpublish

Tags: ezpublish

In my current extension template i need to include template from another extension.
If i write

```
{include uri="design:article/full.tpl"}
```

it will search in my current extension. How can i direct it to other extension? According to doc there is a `name` parameter. What should be value of name?
https://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/3.8/Reference/Template-functions/Miscellaneous/include

Answer (score 1):

The `design` part of the `design:article/full.tpl` is already supposed to do what you want. It will search a `article/full.tpl` template, starting from a `templates`  folder within your design folder `extension/myextension/design`.

eZ Publish will use the following rules to find the good template :

First : determinate which designs are used for the siteaccess. See the `[DesignSettings]` block in your site.ini file**s**

```
[DesignSettings]
SiteDesign=a_design_specific_or_not_to_your_siteaccess
AdditionalSiteDesignList[]=another_generic_design
AdditionalSiteDesignList[]=standard
AdditionalSiteDesignList[]=base
```

Then : determinate which extensions are *offering* a design. See the `[ExtensionSettings]` block in each extension's design.ini file (exemple of the `extension/ezflow/settings/design.ini.append.php`) :

```
[ExtensionSettings]
DesignExtensions[]=ezflow
```

Finally, eZ Publish looks for the template. The `SiteDesign` design will be tried first, and then all the `AdditionalSiteDesignList` designs from top to bottom. Once the template is found, the lookup stops, and this information is cached (even if your TemplaceCache / TemplateCompile / ... is disabled). Remember the cache part, every time you add a new template, meant to be overriding another one, you need to clear the cache.

So if we have only 2 extensions offering a design, say `ezflow` and `mysite`, eZ Publish will try the following paths :

```
extension/mysite/design/a_design_specific_or_not_to_your_siteaccess/templates/full/article.tpl
extension/mysite/design/another_generic_design/templates/full/article.tpl
extension/mysite/design/standard/templates/full/article.tpl
extension/mysite/design/base/templates/full/article.tpl

extension/ezflow/design/a_design_specific_or_not_to_your_siteaccess/templates/full/article.tpl
extension/ezflow/design/another_generic_design/templates/full/article.tpl
extension/ezflow/design/standard/templates/full/article.tpl
extension/ezflow/design/base/templates/full/article.tpl

design/a_design_specific_or_not_to_your_siteaccess/templates/full/article.tpl
design/another_generic_design/templates/full/article.tpl
design/standard/templates/full/article.tpl
design/base/templates/full/article.tpl
```

Note that I made the hypothesis that the `mysite` extension has a higher priority than `ezflow`. See in `settings/override/site.ini.append.php` :

```
[ExtensionSettings]
ActiveExtensions[]
ActiveExtensions[]=mysite
....
ActiveExtensions[]=ezflow
....
```

This is for the `system` templates. The process is a little different when it comes to content templates (the ones which are used by `attribute_view_gui` and `node_view_gui` functions), see https://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/4.x/Templates/The-template-override-system